# problema de reset no código C

Tags: c

Gostaria de ajuda com o código estou com um problema que segue na imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    float CP, LP, PP, LA, AA, AT, AAZ, PL, PC, FP;
    int QA;
    printf ("\nDigite os dados da picina");
    printf ("\nComprimento, Largura, Profundidade: \n");
    {
        scanf("%f,%f, %f", &CP, &LA, &AA);
        PL = 2*CP*PP;
        PC = 2*LP*PP;
        FP = CP*LP;
        AT = PL+PC+FP;
        AAZ = LA*AA;
        QA = ((AT/AAZ)*1.05);
    }
    printf("\nA quantidade de azulejos para o revestimento da piscina e: %f", QA);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: não importa o numero que eu coloque ele da reset e da 0.0000 como resultado e também pula os outros que devo colocar no programa

Comment: Qual o valor da variavel `PP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além do problema apresentado pelo @pmg, você também não está inicializando as variáveis `PP` e `LP`, o que fez com que o programa rodasse com valores desconhecidos para essas variáveis. Ironicamente, esses valores devem ter sido de ordem extremamente baixa quando você rodou seu código (valores como `5.88639522e-039` e `1.12103877e-044`), o que em termos práticos é zero.

Da mesma forma, como as variáveis não foram inicializadas, tais valores poderiam ter sido extremamente elevados, e, consequentemente, o resultado seria outro.

Com isso (considerando `PP` e `LP` nulos), `PL`, `PC` e `FP` também foram zerados pois multiplicam valores `PP` e `LP`.

```
PL = 2*CP*PP;
PC = 2*LP*PP;
FP = CP*LP;
```

E com isso, `AT` também será zero.

```
AT = PL+PC+FP;
```

E, finalmente, `QA` também.

```
QA = ((AT/AAZ)*1.05);
```

Com isso, indepedente do valor de entrada, o resultado será zero (pois QA é zero):

```
printf("\nA quantidade de azulejos para o revestimento da piscina e: %f", QA);
```

Comment: Valores não inicializados são valores não inicializados, podem ser qualquer coisa. Somente globais seriam zero.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Realmente, acabei de conferir aqui. Não são zeradas, mas, ironicamente, assumiram valores muito baixos e por isso mostraram zero na saída quando testei. Mas, da mesma forma, depois de rodar mais vezes, as vezes esses valores podem ser absurdamente altos, quando não inicializados. Vou corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Mete

```
    if (scanf("%f%f%f", &CP, &LA, &AA) != 3) /* erro */;
```

Em vez de

```
    scanf("%f,%f, %f", &CP, &LA, &AA);
```

---

A conversão `"%f, %f, %f"` significa ler um float facultativamente precedido de espaços, uma vírgula, outro float (com espaço facultativo antes), outra vírgula, espaço facultativo, e outro float com espaço facultativo.

Com o input `"10"` as variaveis `LA` e `AA` não são atribuídas e o programa faz contas erradas.

---

Melhor ainda e fazer o input com `fgets()` e depois `sscanf()` para atribuir valor às variáveis

```
printf("Valores? ");
if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) /* error */;
if (sscanf(tmp, "%f%f%f", &CP, &LA, &AA) != 3) /* error */;
```

Comment: o erro ainda persiste, eu consegui fazer em outro código e não deu erro, acho que o erro não seja nestas partes.

Comment: @matheusferreira Você não está inicializado algumas variáveis. O que o pmg respondeu está certo, mas sem alguns valores o resultado não vai mudar.

Comment: sim eu arrumei a parte "%f, %f, %f", estou tentando arrumar um jeito de iniciar eles.